# coverity finds many .h files my build doesn't use

Tags: coverity

In my travis build I let travis download my file, let it run coverity-scan and it outputs SCM data for all 71 source files my project consists of, but then seems to find all .h files the virtual machine contains and chokes on them being more than 15% of the total files.
The relevant lines of output of the coverty-tool are:

```
    71 C/C++ compilation units (100%) are ready for analysis
    Extracting SCM data for 705 files...
```

Does anyone have an idea on what I did wrong? The travis.yml can be read at https://github.com/wxMaxima-developers/wxmaxima/blob/a32e56eff71e256d2c5e7f027a6190324ab9dffb/.travis.yml

Answer (score 0):

Found it: https://scan.coverity.com/scripts/travisci_build_coverity_scan.sh contains the following line that tries to find all the source files containing to the project and ends up with finding all the source files in the whole virtual machine on travis:

```
cov-import-scm --dir $RESULTS_DIR --scm git --log $RESULTS_DIR/scm_log.txt 2>&1
```

Using a local copy of the script and removing this line solves the problem. Additionally if ccache is used the following line is necessary to make coverity collect any data at all for the files that don't need to be re-build:

```
export CCACHE_DISABLE=1
```

The line

```
- echo -n | openssl s_client -connect scan.coverity.com:443 | sed -ne '/-BEGIN CERTIFICATE-/,/-END CERTIFICATE-/p' | sudo tee -a /etc/ssl/certs/ca-
```

other than stated on coverity's homepage must not contain an "https://" ...and if CXXFLAGS doesn't contain an

```
-ansi
```

coverity won't collect any data. With all these changes the coverity build on travis works, but another bug in the travis scripts makes the coverity build return "-1" as exit status: The server gives the unexpected reply "Build uploaded correctly."